# React Native Maps - Displaying markers from JSON file using Google Maps API

Tags: javascript, json, react-native, google-maps-api-3, marker

I'm using the Google Maps API for a screen in my React Native app. Currently I am able to display markers, however they are static - I've written each location in manually, seen below:

```
function MapScreen(props) {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView style={styles.container}>
        <MapView 
          style={StyleSheet.absoluteFillObject}
          customMapStyle={mapStyle}
          showsUserLocation={true}
          provider={PROVIDER_GOOGLE}
          initialRegion={{latitude: 48.859402329205615,longitude: 2.350319507571479,latitudeDelta: 0.112,longitudeDelta: 0.112,}}>
          <Marker 
            coordinate={{latitude: 48.860743444869,longitude: 2.33765948065037,}}
            title="Louvre Museum"
            description="Former historic palace housing huge art collection, from Roman sculptures to da Vinci's 'Mona Lisa.'"
          />
          <Marker 
            coordinate={{latitude: 48.8738950614665,longitude: 2.29503917806517,}}
            title="Arc de Triomphe"
            description="Iconic triumphal arch built to commemorate Napoleon's victories, with an observation deck."
          />
          <Marker 
            coordinate={{latitude: 48.8584176451512,longitude: 2.29446518532972,}}
            title="Eiffel Tower"
            description="Gustave Eiffel's iconic, wrought-iron 1889 tower, with steps and elevators to observation decks."
          />
        </MapView>  
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
}
export default MapScreen;
```

However I was to add many more markers and be able to easily update the map. I have the same data stored in a JSON file, which is stored at the path: **"./constants/ParisLocations.json"**

The JSON is formatted like so:

```
[
 {
   "siteName": "Louvre Museum",
   "Latitude": 48.86074344,
   "Longitude": 2.337659481,
   "Description": "Former historic palace housing huge art collection, from Roman sculptures to da Vinci's \"Mona Lisa.\""
 },
 {
   "siteName": "Arc de Triomphe",
   "Latitude": 48.87389506,
   "Longitude": 2.295039178,
   "Description": "Iconic triumphal arch built to commemorate Napoleon's victories, with an observation deck."
 },
 {
   "siteName": "Eiffel Tower",
   "Latitude": 48.85841765,
   "Longitude": 2.294465185,
   "Description": "Gustave Eiffel's iconic, wrought-iron 1889 tower, with steps and elevators to observation decks."
 },
 {
   "siteName": "Cathédrale Notre-Dame",
   "Latitude": 48.85294707,
   "Longitude": 2.350142233,
   "Description": "Towering, 13th-century cathedral with flying buttresses & gargoyles, setting for Hugo's novel."
 },
 {
   "siteName": "Sacré-Cœur",
   "Latitude": 48.88670304,
   "Longitude": 2.343082828,
   "Description": "Iconic, domed white church, completed in 1914, with interior mosaics, stained-glass windows & crypt."
 }
]
```

Would it be possible to write a function the outputs all the locations as markers from the JSON file?

Comment: If you have tried it then provide your code in the form of a [mcve] along with debugging information instead of complaining about the downvotes. FYI downvotes and close votes are not definite.

Comment: Fruther to that, this has been asked and answered already many times. Do some research before asking. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21401774/add-markers-to-google-maps-from-external-json - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40971251/javascript-adding-markers-on-google-maps-using-json-file - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17514706/cant-load-markers-into-google-maps-api-from-json - etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can load in a local JSON file with this:

```
var json = require('./constants/ParisLocations.json');
```

If the JSON data is on a server, use this:

```
$.getJSON('constants/ParisLocations.json', function(json) {
  ...
});
```

(or `fetch`, or `axios`...)

With the data loaded, loop through it and add your markers.